# How to display results from a search that searches across two entities

Tags: mobile-application, mobile-web, search-results

I am working on a [lyrics site](https://bejebeje.com). The site is very much a work in progress. This is a re-write of the site. On the old site, Google Analytics informed me that 90% of my users were mobile users. So that is what I'm 100% concentrating on.

Here's the mobile experience that I currently have in mind.

[image]

My next thing to work on is search. What I currently have in mind is this:

[image: search button on site]

Once you click that yellow search button, the whole thing slides left, and you get an input box to start searching.

This search will be searching for both lyrics and artists. I need help on the best way of displaying those results to the user.

The user must know what result is an artist and what result is a lyric. Right now, what I have in mind is something like:

[image: search results]

But I am not sure if it works well. I feel like there's not enough distinction between a lyric result and an artist result.

Is this a good way? If not, what is a better way?

Comment: do you have an order in the results (all artists on top)? if yes, you can label the category of resutls, e.g. `Artists:` and then `Songs:`... if not, you could try labeling each result (if there is not enough space you an experiment with background colors or icons and test with users...)

Comment: I could get the API call to return to separate lists, one for artists and one for lyrics. That wouldn't be a problem, but I'm more curious on what would be the best way to display the results. Background colour is a good suggestion, I'll have a play.

Comment: Just a side note, not sure if you already did this but I would recommend that you also create a scenario where the song / artist / band name do not fit in the blue box. I feel that the design you made is to much in a perfect scenario at the moment. What happens when the name is for instance 'The Doors of Perception' or 'One Man Army And The Undead Quartet' (I just googled long band, not sure what kind of music it is).

Comment: To help with making a decision on awarding the bounty, is it possible for you to provide a tick to accept an answer?

Comment: Does your users acually do search or they come directly from google on specific lyrics page? To be honest sounds like you solving false problem

Comment: Yes they do search!

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this. It has two tabs with the search results. Artist and Song are the tabs labels.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to have titles clear enough in search results to separate type of entries... This picture is example of how is done on "UX planet" site

[image]

Comment: On small screen sizes this can be challenging to pull off. [Here's how things look](https://imgur.com/a/CbRN8f3) on my iPhone SE.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you will need to present segmented search results. The most popular music apps like Spotify and Apple Music already do this quite well and I would encourage you to study those apps and implement a similar design pattern so your users don't have to learn a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I agree with what @Aprillion mentioned in the comments. Some other suggestions seem to be more suitable for websites. An integrated search for both songs and artists, with differentiation via background color and/or icons would be best since this is a mobile app with precious limited screen real-estate, though I would personally prefer icons as it will look cleaner.

Also I find the yellow search button placement confusing. In your example, it might mislead the user to think that the search is for 'Canaan Smith' only. It is probably good to have a 'filter' selector for the user to filter only artists, lyrics, or both, and a 'sorting criteria' selector, in case the search results are too many.

In order to incorporate these elements, it would be better to place the yellow search button at the top. Below is what I came out with based on your original designs

[image]
[image]

Comment: On your screens it is hard to distinguish which blocks of content relate to which part of the question. Keep in mind that the OP is asking about distinguishing the results.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a combination of Labels and Tags. Labels will identify each result when presented together and the Filter Tags will let the user filter the results as they wish.**

Material Design use this method called Filter Chips:
[image]

With these tags, the user can select options like checkboxes and can be used in combination with the search function.
[image]

**This method is better than using tabs or icons as they are not scalable. with this approach, if there are more entities to include in the future, it can be done easily.**

[image]

Reference: https://material.io/components/chips/#filter-chips

Comment: The question is *The user must know what result is an artist and what result is a lyric.* You approach only allows to include particular entries into result or to exclude them. But it does not allow to easily **distinguish** what is an artist and what is a lyric,

Comment: @mentallurg Read my answer properly, the label attached to the individual search results delineate the result types clearly. it's written in plain English. Not sure what exactly is your confusion is.

Comment: According to the design, the user has still has to read the text / labels to know what is what. It has the same problems as the screen in OP.

Comment: ... and the 1st part of the answer regarding filter labels is per se OK, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to the question from the OP.

Answer (score -2):

1. Provide separate search, so that user either searches for lyrics or for artists.
2. Provides configuration option so that user decides what has higher relevance, like "lyrics first", "artists first".